# c++ Multiple inheritance and casting

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have the following classes :

```
class A { };
class B { 
public:
B(){}
virtual ~B(){};
};
class B1 : public B{ 
public:
B1(){}
virtual ~B1(){};
};
class B2 : public B{ 
public:
B2(){}
virtual ~B2(){};
};
class C1 : public A, public B1{ 
public:
C1(){}
virtual ~C1(){};
};
class C2 : public A, public B2{ 
public:
C2(){}
virtual ~C2(){};
};
```

I want to know if an object of type B is also of type A :

```
  B*b = new C1(); // or new B, or new C2 ...

  if(dynamic_cast<A*>(b))
  {
    ...
```

Is my dynamic_cast the correct way do that (it compiles and it runs)?
Thank you.

Comment: I think your cast is invalid. Because A and B have mutual children doesn't mean they can be casted to one another.

Comment: Your `b` though you declared it as `B*` was created with `new C1()`, so it is legitimately an `A*` and your code will work.  If you try `new B()`, this will fail.  `C1` inherits from `A`, but `B` does not.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `dynamic_cast` all parents of the object needs to be polymorphic. I.e. you need to add at least one virtual function to the `A` class (like the destructor).

Once you fix that then your `dynamic_cast` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Class A is different than Class B in the C++ type system.  Since they are both empty, they should be same however they are instatiated in memory.  Even empty classes have the identity property.

`dynamic_cast<new_type> (expression)` commonly is used as: `dynamic_cast<derived_type> (myBase)`.  In this case "If expression is a pointer or reference to a polymorphic type Base, and new_type is a pointer or reference to the type Derived a run-time check is performed:"  see cppreference.com search for dynamic_cast.  This allows you to cast the base class back down to the derived class.  The programmer must know that the derived class exists.

Comment: You say that the body of the if statement is executed since all valid pointers are non-zero, but if the dynamic_cast<>() fails, it returns 0, so the way he is checking the result is appropriate.  "If the cast is successful, dynamic_cast returns a value of type new_type. If the cast fails and new_type is a pointer type, it returns a null pointer of that type. If the cast fails and new_type is a reference type, it throws an exception that matches a handler of type std::bad_cast."

Comment: Thanks, I'll amend my answer